# event.currentTarget works locally but not on dev environment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have the following function (simplified for question)

```
myFunction:function(event,key,value){
    var target = event.currentTarget;
    var weekDays = this.state.weekDays;
    var weekDayIndex =  _.findIndex(weekDays, { 'weekDay': target.id})
}
```

when run locally as above it works great,when the code is deployed to dev server it is rendered as follows after webpack tranformation

```
myFunction: function(e, t, n) {
        var o = e.currentTarget
          , a = this.state.weekDays
          , r = d["default"].findIndex(a, {
            weekDay: o.id
        })
}
```

In which case o is null and I get the following error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"
Can anybody shed some light on this?
Thanks

Comment: So you are getting an error about not being able to access the property `id` of `null`? Or...? (I assume you've simplified the function for purposes of this question? Because as shown it doesn't actually do anything - where I'm not counting assignments to variables as "anything" given `weekDayIndex` is never read.)

Comment: yeah it's simplified for the question, the error is:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null" editing question to include this

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in this function and examine what `o` and `e` look like

Comment: o  = null, e = Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: y, _dispatchListeners: null, _dispatchInstances: null, nativeEvent: MouseEvent…}